# stylesheet not rendering in browsers, loads 200 ok

Tags: html, css

I have a stylesheet whose meta tag isn't rendering it in the browser.  It fails to render in all browsers, multiple operating systems.

- All browsers show 200 ok in the Network tabs of their respective dev tools.
- All browsers show the stylesheet is missing or inactive in Sources/Style Editor tab or equivalent.

here is the hardcoded line in the html header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/style-dark.css" media="all" title="Theme" />
```

this stylesheet dictates what theme is used.  placing the url--extracted from the rendered html--in the browser manually after the .com shows the stylesheet fine.  this is how it looks from the view source of the browser

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/style-common.css" title="" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/style-fdb.css" title="FoodDB" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/style-dark.css" media="all" title="Theme" />
```

i added media="all" as a debugging step and for good measure.

I tried in Win7 Chrome, Win7 Firefox, Fedora 25 Chromium, and Fedora FF.

steps i tried:

- rearrange the order of the meta tags.  there are 3 stylesheets.  it's always the 3rd one that fails to render (interesting).
- win7 Firefox Dev Tools Styles Editor actually has an "eye" symbol next to it, so it actually "does" show up, but defaults to the eye icon with a slash through it, evidently indicating that the browser consciously decided not to render it, though it received it fine.  selecting the eye to enable then gets the browser to render it fine.  why does it not enable it automatically?

[Firefox Stylesheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJSnf.png)

Did not find any matches on this site for a solution or on the internet.  There's just no easy way to search the internet as the keywords have too many meanings or are used in too many other problems or just no one has ever had this happen to them.  I changed the site to have 3 styles earlier today and some time later it decided to start not working.  i would not know why there's some limitation on the number of stylesheets.

here are the chrome screenshots

[chrome network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfw6M.png)

[chrome sources tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIxNw.png)

Comment: Not a fix but the `<link>` tag does not use or need a closing slash.

Comment: There is nothing here that allows us to reproduce the problem. Can you read your-site.com/styles/style-common.css in the browser?

Comment: thanks for the replies, and didn't know about the closing slash.   i can view all 3 style sheets in the browser with http://192.168.x.x/styles/...  FF does actually render it "only if" I manually check the eye icon, so i know it loaded fine.

Comment: i added some additional screenshots taken from Chrome dev tools showing style-dark.css shows http 200 code, yet does not show up in sources tab for the engine to render.

Comment: I found out by messing with the title attributes, the stylesheets will or will not be used by the browser, but seems to have no pattern to why.  I can make 2 of the 3 vanish by putting "common" in the the blank one so that only style-dark.css is used.  but if i delete the title attribute on style-dark.css, then all 3 are used by browsers.  i found this is similar: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29036874/style-sheets-break-with-title-attribute-on-link-tags?rq=1" but it doesn't follow the answer.  still, it's definitely with the title attributes.  i will just delete them all.